# Find a Jordan basis $\beta$ for $T$ and calculate $[T]_{\beta, \beta}$And calculate det$(T)$ and trace($T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a vector of  dimension $4$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and $T:V\to V$ is a linear transformation and then there exist nonzero vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$  such that
$$T(v_1)=7v_1+v_2, \;\;T(v_2)=7v_2, \;\;(T-4I)(v_3)=0, \;\;T(v_4)=4v_4$$
Find a  Jordan basis $\beta$ for $T$ and calculate $[T]_{\beta, \beta}$And calculate det$(T)$ and trace($T)$

I really have no idea  to where to  start  ..can you some one help me

Comment: The answer is in the question -- you're already given a Jordan basis for this transformation. For example, do you understand that $v_4$ is an eigenvector for $T$? And do you see what the corresponding eigenvalue (for $v_4$) is?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The third equation can be written as:
$$T (v_3)=4 v_3$$
Then using this what happens with $\beta = (v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4) $ ?